# PHP variable operator for multiple values in a group

Tags: operators

I am trying to write PHP code that can do the following:
If score is less or equal to 50 then print "take a quiz",
elseif score is between 51 and 80 then print "take a test",
else print "you have passed"
So the main proble is how to get operators for between 50 and 80(to count all the numbers from 51 up to 80). Thank you!

Comment: you wouldnt need to count anything, just compare the score

Comment: Here is my code:
$score = 0;
if ($score <= 50) {
echo "Please take a quiz";
} elseif ($score ==51 || $score == 80){
echo "Please take a quiz";
}else {
echo "You have passed";
}

Comment: @JobGondwe See the answers, just like how you don't count from negative infinity to 50 in your `if ($score <= 50)`, the same applies for your elseif -- you can use conditions to compare different numbers, and you are allowed to use multiple conditions in the same condition, though in this case this isn't needed due to the wonders of `else` (and `elseif`) assuming score is an integer. As I say, see the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for this

```
    if($score <= 50)
      echo 'take a quiz';
    else if($score < 80)
      echo 'take a test';
    else echo 'you have passed';
```

Comment: Actually this works ...I think i was over-thinking, thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to combine three operators, the `>`, `<`, and `&&`.

The `&&` operator evaluates its left and right hand side and returns a truthy value if both of them are truthy, and a falsey value if one or both of them are falsey. (The returned value will be one of the arguments).

This is called an *and* operator because it return a truthy value only if A and B are true.

To combine everything, one would do `if($score < 82 && $score > 50)`.

**However, there's actually an easier way in this case.**

Assuming that `$score` is an integer, it's greater than or equal to 51 if it isn't less than 50. And since the else-if won't run unless all previous clauses in the if statement didn't run (i.e. only one of the possible code blocks will run), then you only have to check that `$score` is less than 80).

So that means, in this case, while the `&&` operator could be used, we could just write

```
if($score < 50) {
    // ...
else if ($score < 80) { // "else if" won't run if ($score < 50) was false.
    // ...
} else { // won't run unless ($score < 80) and ($score < 50) were both false
    // ...
}
```

That's why the idea of `else` is very useful.